# Ember.js Route Mappings

Tags: javascript, ember.js, routes, ember-router

I am very new to ember.js and I am try to setup the routes/resources for my application in `App.Router.map`, however I am having a bit of trouble with coming up with the most efficient/DRY-est way to define the routes that the app needs.

I want to have a resource `items`, which is to be the default route when coming into the application, it displays a list of items which is filtered by a dynamic segment `:bucket`, that must be one of set of predefined bucket names. i.e. `#/items/foo`, or `#/items/bar`, where `foo` and `bar` are valid `:bucket` values.

Additionally, the `items` route should also allow a second segment called `tag`, which then must be followed by another dynamic segment which is a url-safe version of the tag name, i.e. `#/items/tag/my-tag`.

I have the first part working, using:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
   this.resource('items', {path: '/items/:bucket'}); 
});
```

However, i am unable to figure out how to fit the `tag` version of the route in there. I've tried both nesting it inside the `items` resource and also as its own top level resource, but neither works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can structure your router like this:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('items', {path: '/items'}, function(){
    this.route('bucket', {path: '/:bucket'});
    this.route('tag', {path: '/tag/:tag'});
  });
});
```

This shows all `Item`s at `#/items` and filters by bucket at `#/items/bucketNameHere` and by tags at `#/items/tag/tagNameHere`.

If all items are displayed in the `ItemRoute`:

```
App.ItemsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(){
      return this.store.find('item');
  }
});
```

Then you can handle the filtering in the `ItemsBucketRoute` and `ItemsTagRoute`:

```
App.ItemsBucketRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params){
    console.log("model fired");
    return this.modelFor('items').filterProperty('bucket', params.bucket);
  }
});

App.ItemsTagRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params){
    return this.modelFor('items').filterProperty('tag', params.tag);
  }
});
```

You can also accomplish list filtering [using the `filterProperty` of `arrayController`s](http://www.kaspertidemann.com/how-to-filter-an-array-of-records-by-a-property-value-in-ember-js/).

[JSBin Example](http://jsbin.com/ucanam/1451/edit)

Comment: Looks great, thank you! Couple quick questions, I should be able to define all my route `actions` on just `ItemsRoute` and they will be used even if the `ItemsBucketRoute` or `ItemsTagRoute` is currently active, due to bubbling correct? Also, if the user navigates to just `#/items`, I can force a default bucket by just using the `ItemsRoute`'s `redirect` hook right?

Comment: Yes, and yes. If you have a dynamic route you will need to supply the model as well: http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_transitionTo